# I finally found the answer to my bounty question from months ago, now what?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I finally have the answer to my bounty question from last year. I've posted the answer in my question but I cannot accept it. What should I do for this case?

Comment: I hate it when people mention a particular question then don't provide a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your question, leave the contents the same but on the bottom add something like

**EDIT:** I found the answer see below posted by me

Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Flag the answer for moderator attention and ask that they consider changing the accepted answer.

Alternately, post a new question with the correct answer, and ask on meta for help closing the old one as a duplicate of the new one.